# Increase the sound in each 5 seconds through Media Player

Tags: android, media-player

I want to increase the sound by one level up in each and every 5 seconds meanwhile the sound clip plays.Below is my code:-

```
MediaPlayer player;
        player=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm);
        player.setLooping(true);
```

Is there any method in which i can track each and every 5 minutes when over.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with java `TimerTask`, this is an example code, not tested but should work with no big modifications :

Basically you start a task every 5 seconds, in the `run()` function of the `TimerTask` you level up your sound level, and when you reach the `maxSoundLevel` you call `cancel()` to stop the task.

```
//Put this in global
int REFRESH_INTERVAL = 5 * 1000; //5 seconds
int maxSoundLevel = 10; // Number of loop to get to max level
int curSoundLevel = 0; //Start at 0 volume level

//Put this after you started the sound
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 0, REFRESH_INTERVAL);

//Put this after your method
private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    public void run() {
       if(curSoundLevel < maxSoundLevel)
       {
           float logLevel = (float)(Math.log(maxSoundLevel-curSoundLevel)/Math.log(maxSoundLevel));
           yourMediaPlayer.setVolume(1-logLevel);
           curSoundLevel ++;
        }
        else {
            this.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have more questions feel free to ask me.